# R program : stacked barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R programming. I want to create a stacked bar chart (using any library like ggplot2) for the below data format.

```
s no    type    state
t1  type1   A
t2  type2   C
t3  type3   A
t4  type1   B
t5  type3   B
t6  type3   B
t7  type3   C
t8  type2   A
t9  type2   C
t10 type2   B
```

Want to render chart with 'state' on X-axis and 'type' on y axis (count of each type as stacked bar). I tried plotting where numerical value is directly available in column. here I'm finding difficulty in taking the count for unique states and unique type.

Comment: There are many questions on SO for stacked bar graphs and `ggplot2`. If none of these fit your scenario, then please add links to your question with these posts and explain why the solutions don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ggplot2 to map the variables to the aesthetics just as you described. You don't want `type` on the y-axis - you want type on another axis, in this case `fill` for stacks of different colors. The default y aesthetic for a bar plot is count.

```
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- read.csv(
  text = "s no,type,state
  t1,type1,A
  t2,type2,C
  t3,type3,A
  t4,type1,B
  t5,type3,B
  t6,type3,B
  t7,type3,C
  t8,type2,A
  t9,type2,C
  t10,type2,B")


ggplot(mydata, aes(x = state, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]